# Get Distinct Column Count By Day

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle 12c and I need to get the count of unique username rows for each day. Currently the table below has multiple rows with the same username on the same day (date_created).

```
LOGIN_HISTORY
----------------
id (unique random generated long)
date_created (timestamp)
username (var char)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query below I group using the day, month, and year, which is required to uniquely identify each day your `date_created` column.  I used `COUNT(DISTINCT username)` to identify the count of unique usernames for a given day.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date_created, 'DD') DAY,
       TO_CHAR(date_created, 'MM') MONTH,
       TO_CHAR(date_created, 'YYYY') YEAR,
       COUNT(DISTINCT username) AS userCount
FROM LOGIN_HISTORY
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(date_created, 'DD'),
         TO_CHAR(date_created, 'MM'),
         TO_CHAR(date_created, 'YYYY')
```

Comment: I'd use `TRUNC(date_created)` instead of the TO_CHAR but this looks correct too.